# What's the Pythonic way to "repeat this until condition met -or- maximum achieved"?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm still learning Python, and I wonder if there's a "more Pythonic" way for the following:

```
MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5
for i in range(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
    response = do_something()
    do_something_based_on(response)
    do_another_thing_based_on(response)
    if response == 0:
        do_something_if_success()
        break
```

***Edit:*** Apologies, I might have over simplified the case. I need to use the `response` before the final check, so I have to capture it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a perfectly valid way to implement what you want.

It's probably possible to do this in various more functional-like ways, including one with double recursive generators, but I suspect none would be as straightforward as this.

Comment: Sounds... complex :D   Yeah, I guess sometimes I overthink things too much trying to be Pythonic :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this way would save more memory than yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5
for i in xrange(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
    if 0 == do_something():
        do_something_if_success()
        break
```

EDIT:

Update according to latest quesiton.

```
MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5
for i in xrange(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
    response = do_something()
    do_something_based_on(response)
    do_another_thing_based_on(response)
    if 0 == response:
        do_something_if_success()
        break
```

Comment: Ahahaha, make sense. I might've oversimplified the case... the `response` variable is actually used before the `if` statement. I'll edit my posting.

Comment: @pepoluan Then I think just replacing 'range' with 'xrange' would be enough. Writing 0 before '==' is a recommended way to avoid writing as '=' by mistake. BTW, I think PEP8 will answer lots of your questions.

Comment: @pepoluan Oh, you can also do `if not response:`